# Encrypting Org export

Tags: org-mode, org-export, encryption

I have a GPG encrypted Org file (`title.org.gpg`) that I interact with transparently using `epa`. I would like to export this to a GPG encrypted PDF. Currently I do this by using the usual LaTeX export (<kbd>C-c C-e l</kbd>...), manually encrypting afterwards. How would I go about having Org do this automatically?